# Issue on Chrome - Javascript list view

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-view, internet-explorer, chrome

I have an issue with this simple Javascript code into a SharePoint **list view page**.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2").append("<p>myTest</p>");
        //do stuff with id
    });
</script>
```

This code is **running in IE** but **not in Chrome**, why?
I am using a *Script editor web part*.

Comment: Probably because it executes in Chrome before your DOM has finished loading. Take a look here for steps to mitigate: http://blog.tallan.com/2012/10/01/use-sp-sod-executefuncabc-to-load-the-sharepoint-javascript-libraries-when-needed/

Comment: It should be inside dom.ready

Comment: But jQuery's DOM ready does not take in to account DOM objects renders client side (which are a few in SharePoint, hence the existence of the specific SP.SOD.executeFunc etc.)

Comment: it works! I used ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome the code was exectued before the load of the DOM.
I used this to solve my problem:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunc, "sp.js");
    });

    function myFunc(){
        $("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ2").append("<p>myTest</p>");
        //do stuff with id
    }
</script>
```

Thanks to @Robert Lindgren